# I want to increase the number of files that can be GCP deployed to 10,000 or more

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine

After adding a new library in my local environment and deploying to GCP I got the following error.

```
$ gcloud app deploy
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) INVALID_ARGUMENT: This deployment has too many files. New versions are limited to 10000 files for this app.
- '@type': type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest
  fieldViolations:
  - description: This deployment has too many files. New versions are limited to 10000
      files for this app.
    field: version.deployment.files[...]
```

I think this error can be avoided by sending a cap increase request, but I've never done that so I don't know what to do.
How can I raise the limit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really have more than the 10000 files quota in the service you're trying to deploy then you might have to reduce the number accordingly.

There is a know limit in [this quota](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/quotas#Deployments).Also, according to [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/quotas#When_a_Resource_is_Depleted)

```
Is your app exceeding the default limits? If you have Silver, Gold, or Platinum support package, you can contact your support representative to request higher throughput limits
```

Moreover, here are somethings you can try:

1. You might be able to get a quota increase, see Getting error on GAE: Max number [of files and blobs is 10000](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/quotas#Deployments)
2. Delete whatever files are not actually needed, or just skip them during deployment see [skip_files](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#skip_files) or, for the more recent cloud SDK versions, the [.gcloudignore file](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/gcloudignore) .
3. If you have a lot of static files consider moving (some of) them to GCS instead:
   You could have your app store the images in Google Cloud Storage [GCS](https://cloud.google.com/storage/), as app data, not as app static files, so they wouldn't count towards the app's 10k files limit.
4. Split the service into multiple smaller services - each with its own 10000 files limit.

Comment: I also considered using ".gcloudignore", but I can't reduce the number of files because I need a newly added file.
I don't know the specific of 3 and 4, so can I ask for the specific procedure?

Comment: Here you can find information about [Structuring Web Services in App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/configuration-files)